# How do I add a number to each element in array using for loop?

Tags: javascript

There are few issues in my code and I just can't seem to find them. Here is my code with the expected log commented.

```
function addN(arr, n){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        return arr[i] + n
    }
  } 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4]), 2) // expected log [7, 6]
```

Comment: What does `return` statement do?

Comment: You are passing `2` to `console.log`, not `add`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you meant:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  return arr.map(el => el + n)
} 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4], 2)) // expected log [7, 6]
```

And if you need to do it with a for loop:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  const ret = [];
  for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    ret.push(arr[i]+n)
  }
  return ret;
} 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4], 2)) // expected log [7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are looping once and building your array, then before you finish the building of the array using the loop, you return.

You should return after the loop inside your function. Here is using a forEach loop... You could also use map as well...

```js
let array = [4, 5];

function addN(arr, n) {
  arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
    arr[i] = el + n;    
  });
  return arr;
};

console.log(addN(array, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You are not passing `2` to `addN()`, you are passing it to `console.log()`
2. You are `return`ing from the for loop. The `return` statement returns a value and halts the function completely. Instead, you need to return an array.

So, the final code would be:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   arr[i] += n
  }
  return arr
} 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4], 2))
```

Although, you could easily use `Array.prototype.map` to do this:

```js
function addN(arr, n){
  return arr.map(item => item + n)
} 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4], 2))
```

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

First, your console.log statement is incorrectly written. It should be `console.log(addN([5,4],2))` you were missing a parenthesis / had it in the wrong place. Now about your function:

When a function hits `return` it stops the function and sends the value to the function. So the way you have it written, it will stop the loop after the very first loop because it hits a return. You want it to loop through until it reaches the end of the array AND THEN `return` a value. See code below:

```
function addN(arr, n){

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] + n
        //the 'if' statement below won't trigger until the for loop is complete
        if (i===arr.length-1) {
        return arr
        }
    }
  } 
  
console.log(addN([5, 4], 2))
```